# Way to return index (date) and columns header in a dataframe if a condition is fullfilled

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new in python. I wanted to create a function that will return me the date and features (A, B or C) which changed its value by 10%.

here is how the simplified original data looks like

```
| Date     | A      | B     | C    |
|:-------- |:------:| -----:|-----:|
| 2020-1-1 | 10.0   | 3.0   | 1.0  |
| 2020-1-2 | 10.0   | 3.0   | 1.2  |
| 2020-1-3 | 10.0   | 3.3   | 1.0  |
| 2020-1-4 | 11.0   | 3.3   | 1.0  |
```

I created the percentage difference from this table by doing the `pct_change()`.

```
| Date     | A      | B     | C    |
|:-------- |:------:| -----:|-----:|
| 2020-1-1 | Nan    | Nan   | Nan  |
| 2020-1-2 | 0      | 0     | 0.2  |
| 2020-1-3 | 0      | 0.1   | -0.2 |
| 2020-1-4 | 0.1    | 0     | 0    |
```

If i have one features only (A for example), i can just do `df[df['A'] > 0.1]`to get the date. But with A, B and C...i don't know how to deal with it.
The results i want will be something like this:

- A, 2020-1-4, 0.1
- B, 2020-1-3, 0.1
- C, 2020-1-2, 0.2
- C, 2020-1-3, -0.2

I am not sure if my wish is too much but my knowledge and skill can't defintely cope with it.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is kind of confusing, but maybe the code bellow can help you.

Try this:

```
df[df>0.1]
```

If you want to return only when entire rows are >0.1 use this:

```
df[df>0.1].dropna(how='any')
```

Edit:

You can also use unstack function and then you can filter de results.

```
df_2 = df.unstack()  # use df.abs() if you want the absolut difference
df_2 = df_2[df_2>0.1]
# The output will be a series. You can convert it back to dataframe using:
df_2 = df_2.to_frame()
```

Comment: The unstack function made it!!I never thought there is another option other than doing a function or a loop through all the columns. you made my day! i was so unease yesterday and needed to went jogging at night to calm my mind :D Thank you so much for your amazing help.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Loopings, in my opinion, are the last way to solve something on Python, but I'm not an expert. If you think my question is enough, you can accept it in the check icon.